# Camunda Human Task not blocking users from other group from claiming the task

Tags: task, bpmn, camunda, access-rights

I am constructing a PoC using camunda BPM running on Springboot. I am starting with a simple process and would like to efficiently use all the access rights restrictions such as candidate groups assignment. Here is my process:

[image]

Regardless of what the tasks does, I am trying to set the candidate groups for a human task so that users from other group cannot claim or see the task in their task list under the cockpit. They can even finish the whole process, even if they don't belong to any candidate groups configured, or not being the candidate user configured.

Does any one know if there are some configuration to be done, or how to properly enforce the allowed groups for a task execution and claim?

Comment: Small note: I do not wish to add filters so that users choose the filter and see the ones that are related to their group. I want them to not be able to see the ones assigned to other groups, without the possibility to remove the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Camunda 7. You need to set the property

```
camunda.bpm.authorization.enabled = true
```

to enable authorizations. They are disabled by default.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/process-engine/authorization-service/

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/webapps/admin/authorization-management/

Comment: Thanks! that worked perfectly with a couple of little config as well!